# difference between sizeof and strlen in C linux

Tags: c, linux, sizeof, strlen

The first printf statement is giving output 3 and second giving 20. 
Can anybody please explain what's the difference between the two here?

```
char frame[20],str[20];
printf("\nstrlen(frame)= %d",strlen(frame));
printf("\nsizeof(frame) = %d",sizeof(frame));
```

Thanks :)

Comment: One is length of the string the other size of the pointer. This is basic C knowledge :)

Comment: @Stolas none is the size of the pointer, though one is the size of the array.

Comment: `strlen()` evals *content* at **run-time** for its computation. `sizeof` is deduced at **compile-time** and is content-agnostic. *Both* are covered in any remotely-decent text on the C language.

Comment: @Stolas , in addition to nos comment, sizeof pointer is 4 on my system.

Comment: @WhozCraig could you please tell me why sizeof is returning 3 even if it's compiled time.

Comment: I stand corrected. I forgot the array over the malloc.

Comment: @user3542109 You are getting `strlen(frame) --> 3` because of the _garbage_ in `frame[20]` when code runs as `frame` is not initialized.  Another day or on another system you may get something different - it is undefined behavior.

Comment: @user3542109 Sure, your program is executing undefined behavior. You're using an incorrect format-specifier. `sizeof()` evaluates to type `size_t`, yet your invoking `printf()` telling it the value is a system `int`. use `%zu` for your second `printf()`. *Both* lines invoke UB (the former invokes `strlen()` on a buffer with indeterminate content, the latter for the reasons I just said).

Comment: @WhozCraig thanks for pointing me over it. I usually don't do it. but will do from now :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Because the contents of `frame` is not initialized, which means it is not a valid C string, so `strlen(frame)` could return any value, or crash. Actually, its behavior is undefined in this case.
2. Because `frame` is an array of 20 characters, therefore `sizeof(frame)` will return `20 * sizeof(char)`, which will always be 20 (`sizeof(char)` always equals 1).

Comment: It's always giving 3 only.

Comment: @user3542109 Have you tested it on another operating system? Or building it with another compiler?

Comment: no.. u mean it has a value for a (system,compiler) ?

Comment: @user3542109 No, it could have any value literally, it even could change from run to run of your program. It is one of the undefined behaviors of C.

Comment: ok.. I will try it tomorrow. Today it's giving 3 every time. Still thanks a lot for explaining beautifully :)

Answer (score 6):

`sizeof` is a compile-time operator and determines the size in bytes that a type consumes. In the case of `frame` (`char[20]`) that is 20 bytes.

`strlen` is a run-time function and scans a given pointer until the first occurrence of a nul terminator `'\0'` returning the amount of characters until then.

Comment: @user3542109 Because frame[] is an uninitialized array, and it probably contains bogus characters up to frame[3], which is '\0'. If you would declare it as "char frame[20] = {0}", strlen() would return 0

Answer (score 3):

strlen actually gives you the length of the string, whereas sizeof gives you the size of the allocated memory in bytes. It is infact quite nicely explained here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/ Extract given below.

> The length of a C string is determined by the terminating null-character: A C string is as long as the number of characters between the beginning of the string and the terminating null character (without including the terminating null character itself).
>
> This should not be confused with the size of the array that holds the string. For example:
>
> char mystr[100]="test string";
>
> defines an array of characters with a size of 100 chars, but the C string with which mystr has been initialized has a length of only 11 characters. Therefore, while sizeof(mystr) evaluates to 100, strlen(mystr) returns 11.

And yes as per the other comments, you are trying to get length for uninitialized strings and that leads to undefined behaviour, it can be 3 or anything else, depending on whatever garbage is present in the memory that got allocated for your string.